# How is android.database different from android.database.sqlite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, package

I am trying to develop this android application whose database is not stored in the device but on a server. To use sqlite database I need to use `android.database.sqlite`; and I haven't made much use of `android.database` package. I went through the documentation site but it did not state clearly if it's possible can store my `sqlite database` file on server and invoke methods to access it from there. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is not an ideal database to use on a server.  The andriod.database.sqlite package is going to have resources for dealing with sqlite specifically, where the android.database package is going to have generic database resources, not specific to sqlite.

For using sqlite on a server, first bear in mind that concurrent connections are a big no-no... sqlite is not designed to handle them.

If I still felt I had to do this, I'd probably look at creating an adapter on the server which would accept requests from the application, then use the android.database.sqlite package on the server, as it's local per the scope there (as sqlite is designed for).

https://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html